# カレンダーとプルダウンを連動させるjavascriptの設定の仕方がわかりません。

Tags: javascript, html5

webデザインを初めて1年目の素人です。
お答え頂ければ幸いです。

現在、プルダウンと連動したカレンダー機能を作成しているのですが、うまくいきません。

希望の表示としては、
・カレンダーアイコンをクリックするとカレンダーが表示される。
・カレンダーの日付をクリックするとプルダウンも連動して変わる。

カレンダーアイコンをクリックしてカレンダーが表示する部分はうまくいきました。

最初、プルダウンを年と月と日を分けて作成していて、その時は連動して表示ができたのですが、
年と月を合体させた表示で連動させようとすると、年月のプルダウンは変化せず、
日の部分に月の数字が入ってしまうといった表示になります。

参考にしたサイトは
[https://beanb.wordpress.com/2014/10/29/フォームとカレンダーを連動（プルダウン）/](https://beanb.wordpress.com/2014/10/29/%E3%83%95%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E3%81%A8%E3%82%AB%E3%83%AC%E3%83%B3%E3%83%80%E3%83%BC%E3%82%92%E9%80%A3%E5%8B%95%EF%BC%88%E3%83%97%E3%83%AB%E3%83%80%E3%82%A6%E3%83%B3%EF%BC%89/)
http://www.tabikobo.com/
の2つを参考にしました。

カレンダー部分の記述を簡単に書いていくと、
【HTML】

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <dd id="date" class="form-inline-fix calender">

        <div class="sp-block">
            <select  id="year_month" class="form-control w-s">
                <option value="">指定なし</option>
            </select><span>月</span>

            <select  id="day" class="form-control w-s">
                <option value="">指定なし</option>
            </select><span>日</span>
            <input type="hidden"  name="" value="" />
        </div>
    </dd>
</body>
```

【JS】

```
//以下は日程のプルダウンとカレンダー
function updateSelected(date){
    console.log(date);
    $('#year_month').val(date.substring(0, 4)+'-'+date.substring(5, 7));
    $('#day').val(date.substring(8, 10));
}
$(function(){

    var myD = new Date();
    var myYear = myD.getFullYear();
    var myMonth = myD.getMonth() + 1;
    for (i = myMonth; i <= 12; i++) {
        var val = myYear + '-' + ('00' + i).slice(-2);
        var html = myYear + '年' + ('00' + i).slice(-2) + '月';
        $('#year_month').append($('<option />').val(val).html(html));
    }
    var myYear = myYear + 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= myMonth; i++) {
        var val = myYear + '-' + ('00' + i).slice(-2);
        var html = myYear + '年' + ('00' + i).slice(-2) + '月';
        $('#year_month').append($('<option />').val(val).html(html));
    }
    //1〜31の数字を生成
    for (var i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
        if (i < 10) {
            i = '0' + i;
        }
        $('#day').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));
    }

    //カレンダーからプルダウンを更新
    $('.calender').each(function() {
        var id = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
        $(id + ' input').bind('change', function() {
            var i = 0;
            var dates = $(this).val().split('/');
            $(id + ' select').each(function() {
            var year = dates[0];
                $(this).val(dates[i]);
                i++;
            });
        });
    });

    //プルダウンからカレンダーを更新
    $('.calender').each(function() {
        var id = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
        $(id + ' select').bind('change', function() {
            var i = 1;
            var dates = new Array(3);
            $(id + ' select').each(function() {
                dates[i] = $(this).val();
                i++;
            });
            var newdate = dates[0] + '/' + dates[1] + '/' + dates[2];
            $(id + ' input').val(newdate);
        });
    });

    //カレンダーの表示
    var date = new Date();
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonText:'',
        //buttonImage: '../img/calender.jpg',
        //buttonImageOnly: false,
        closeText: '閉じる',
        prevText: '前',
        nextText: '次',
        currentText: '今日',
        monthNames: ['1月','2月','3月','4月','5月','6月',
                     '7月','8月','9月','10月','11月','12月'],
        monthNamesShort: ['1月','2月','3月','4月','5月','6月',
                          '7月','8月','9月','10月','11月','12月'],
        dayNames: ['日曜日','月曜日','火曜日','水曜日','木曜日','金曜日','土曜日'],
        dayNamesShort: ['日','月','火','水','木','金','土'],
        dayNamesMin: ['日','月','火','水','木','金','土'],
        weekHeader: '週',
        dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
        firstDay: 0,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: true,
        yearSuffix: '年',
        minDate: new Date(year, 1 - 1, 1),
        maxDate: new Date(year + 1, 12 - 1, 31)
    });
    $('.calender input').datepicker();

    //$('#ui-datepicker-div').hide();
});
```

という形になっています。

JSの設定の問題かと思うのですが原因がわかりません。

どなたかご教授お願いいたします。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/29485 マルチポスト

Answer (score 1):

以下の二つ部分を修正すれば、問題ないになります

**【JS】**

```
//カレンダーからプルダウンを更新
$('.calender').each(function() {
    var id = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
    $(id + ' input').bind('change', function() {
        var i = 0;
        var dates = $(this).val().split('/');
        $(id + ' select')[0].value = dates[0]+'-'+dates[1];
        $(id + ' select')[1].value = dates[2];
    });
});

//プルダウンからカレンダーを更新
$('.calender').each(function() {
    var id = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
    $(id + ' select').bind('change', function() {
        var i = 0;
        var dates = new Array(2);
        $(id + ' select').each(function() {
            dates[i] = $(this).val();
            i++;
        });
        var newdate = dates[0].replace('-','/') + '/' + dates[1];
        $(id + ' input').val(newdate);
    });
});
```

修正した後の結果：

```js
//以下は日程のプルダウンとカレンダー
function updateSelected(date){
    console.log(date);
    $('#year_month').val(date.substring(0, 4)+'-'+date.substring(5, 7));
    $('#day').val(date.substring(8, 10));
}
$(function(){

    var myD = new Date();
    var myYear = myD.getFullYear();
    var myMonth = myD.getMonth() + 1;
    for (i = myMonth; i <= 12; i++) {
        var val = myYear + '-' + ('00' + i).slice(-2);
        var html = myYear + '年' + ('00' + i).slice(-2) + '月';
        $('#year_month').append($('<option />').val(val).html(html));
    }
    var myYear = myYear + 1;
    for (i = 1; i <= myMonth; i++) {
        var val = myYear + '-' + ('00' + i).slice(-2);
        var html = myYear + '年' + ('00' + i).slice(-2) + '月';
        $('#year_month').append($('<option />').val(val).html(html));
    }
    //1〜31の数字を生成
    for (var i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
        if (i < 10) {
            i = '0' + i;
        }
        $('#day').append($('<option />').val(i).html(i));
    }

    //カレンダーからプルダウンを更新
    $('.calender').each(function() {
        var id = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
        $(id + ' input').bind('change', function() {
            var i = 0;
            var dates = $(this).val().split('/');
            $(id + ' select')[0].value=dates[0]+'-'+dates[1];
   $(id + ' select')[1].value=dates[2];
        });
    });

    //プルダウンからカレンダーを更新
    $('.calender').each(function() {
        var id = '#' + $(this).attr('id');
        $(id + ' select').bind('change', function() {
            var i = 0;
            var dates = new Array(2);
            $(id + ' select').each(function() {
                dates[i] = $(this).val();
                i++;
            });
            var newdate = dates[0].replace('-','/') + '/' + dates[1];
            $(id + ' input').val(newdate);
        });
    });

    //カレンダーの表示
    var date = new Date();
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonText:'○',
        //buttonImage: '../img/calender.jpg',
        //buttonImageOnly: false,
        closeText: '閉じる',
        prevText: '前',
        nextText: '次',
        currentText: '今日',
        monthNames: ['1月','2月','3月','4月','5月','6月',
                     '7月','8月','9月','10月','11月','12月'],
        monthNamesShort: ['1月','2月','3月','4月','5月','6月',
                          '7月','8月','9月','10月','11月','12月'],
        dayNames: ['日曜日','月曜日','火曜日','水曜日','木曜日','金曜日','土曜日'],
        dayNamesShort: ['日','月','火','水','木','金','土'],
        dayNamesMin: ['日','月','火','水','木','金','土'],
        weekHeader: '週',
        dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
        firstDay: 0,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: true,
        yearSuffix: '年',
        minDate: new Date(year, 1 - 1, 1),
        maxDate: new Date(year + 1, 12 - 1, 31)
    });
    $('.calender input').datepicker();

    $('#ui-datepicker-div').hide();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" media="all" />
</head>

<body>
    <dd id="date" class="form-inline-fix calender">

        <div class="sp-block">
            <select  id="year_month" class="form-control w-s">
                <option value="">指定なし</option>
            </select><span>月</span>

            <select  id="day" class="form-control w-s">
                <option value="">指定なし</option>
            </select><span>日</span>
            <input type="hidden"  name="" value="" />
        </div>
    </dd>


</body>

</html>
```